# is ther a plugin that will hide/show content for a scheduled period of time?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, html, content

We would like to post some html during a specific time on a given day of the week.
For instance: *Imagine a website for a TV station that wants to show what is on the air right now.*

I am looking for a plugin that will do this. We will pay. I found something at this site:
http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/scheduled-content/

I do not want to subscribe to all their other stuff, just to get one plugin.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: OK, Plan B - can anyone suggest a plugin that will let a site owner schedule slider panels? Same scenario as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can join their group for free and then buy a one month subscription with one product for $39.

YOU MUST remember to discontinue the subscription before the month is up or you will be billed again automatically.

Not my favorite solution. But it IS a solution.